# Rails UTF8-encoding Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8

I'm very new to rails.

I have an existing MS SQL DB and build the rails-app on it. I just scaffolded all required stuff from the existing tables.

But, I have an Umlaut in my index.html.erb source code.

```
<td><%= wohnung.Grösse %></td>
```

But this raises an **500 Internal Server Error**.

The development.log doesn't helps me...:

```
Started GET "/wohnungs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-05 13:52:24 +0100
Processing by WohnungsController#index as HTML
[1m[36mWohnung Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mEXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [Wohnung].* FROM [Wohnung]'[0m
Rendered wohnungs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 62ms
```

If I remove this line, it works. But every other umlaut in texts is represented by a '�' ...

What I did:

- Added '#coding: utf-8' on top of the wohnung_controller
- Added 'encoding: utf8' to the database.yml,
- Added 'config.encoding = "utf-8"' to the application.rb,
- Added *meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"* to the application.html.erb-file.

I've no idea what I could do next...Please help :)

Greetings,
Beasty

Comment: Not sure if its a typo but, '#coding: utf-8' on top of the wohnung_controller must read '#encoding: utf-8'

Comment: Yep, it was an typo... The error occurs in the the *.html.erb files actually. But I added meta-tags for the unicode etc. But nothing changes, I still got the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a less problematic circumscription like `wohnung.groesse` ? You probably only have to rename a database column. It is not recommendable to use special characters in a function or database column name.

Comment: Yeah it's generally a bad idea to put non-ASCII characters in method names, it only generates problems (like this one).

Comment: Yes you're right. I'll rename them, Thanks :-) But I've still the problem, that the umlauts in my text aren't displayed correctly. The umlauts are represented by an �-icon. (Those strings from the db-entry in the webpage...) How to solve that? :/

Comment: utf8 is the right encoding. If the database has the charset utf8 it should work. You can select the encoding in the database.yml and in the rails migration create_table through the option 'DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

Comment: Hi. It looks like the db has the encoding 'latin 1'...Could this be the reason for the misbehaviour with the umlauts?

Comment: yes, of course. You can change the default character set for a MySQL database or table with ALTER DATABASE or ALTER TABLE, see also here: http://woss.name/2006/10/25/migrating-your-rails-application-to-unicode/

Comment: hmm...i cant find any useful informations how to do that with Microsoft SQL Server. If I create a new database, utf 8 isn't listed. :/